# How do I change a elements name that was cloned with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the name of the input box. In the code I have the name start out at myText0 and I want the clones to be changing in increments of myText1, myText2, myText3, myText4... depending on the number of boxes added so that every input box is named differently.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php
$num = 0;
echo '
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
    <div><input type="text" name="'.${'myText'.$num.}.'"></div>
</div>
';
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            //${myText.$num}
            // I don't know how to add this without php code to keep changing every added input box.
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="myText"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>').clone(true); //add input box
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
</script>
```

Comment: `name="myText"` -> `name="myText' + x + '"`

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you have two alternatives:

1. Have the first text field, and for every new input, you just clone it, get the reference to that clone, and then update its name attribute, and append it to the wrapper.
2. Append directly to the wrapper the input element, creating a new one every time you need.

For the second option, I've just modified your code:

- There's no need to clone the element when appending it to the wrapper.
- You must test for `x <= max_fields`.

--

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initial text box count

    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x <= max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="myText' + x + '"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
            x++; //text box increment
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
        x--;
    })
});
</script>
```

Comment: This would be a good answer, but you're not assigning the desired IDs to the new input boxes, as was requested.

Comment: The OP is not asking for updated IDs, just updated name attributes. Or did I read wrong?

Comment: I meant names - thank you for the correction (whoops!).  However, what I was saying holds true, irrespective of the attribute to which your logic is applied.

Comment: Thank you for your correction as well. I appended the x variable in a draft I wrote and didn't write it here in the final answer.

Comment: Nice - However, your code would result in duplicate names (almost typed IDs) if an input that WASN'T the last one was removed.

Comment: Example:  Input 1 is added.  Input 2 is added. (x is now 3).  Input 1 is removed (x is now 2).  Input 2 is added for a second time, causing a conflict.

Comment: You're right. I just modified the OP code to update properly the name attribute. The problem you have envisioned goes beyond OP's question.

Comment: That is true, but any answer that only addresses what was asked will inevitably result in errors.  I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you are calling clone on hard coded html in javascript. Below's code will append the div to the html and set the name property on the new eleemnt

```
$('<div><input type="text"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>').appendTo(wrapper).children("input").prop("name", "myText" + x); //add input box
```

Comment: This will work unless a field is removed and then another added, in which case you would either get multiple IDs - or your IDs would skip a number (depending on how you're calculating "x")

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using unobtrusive javascript:

```js
function createNewInput() {
 
 var inputDiv = document.querySelector('button + div');
 var inputs = inputDiv.getElementsByTagName('input');
 var lastInput = inputs[(inputs.length - 1)];
 var lastInputX = Number(lastInput.getAttribute('name').match(/\d+$/));

 var newInput = document.createElement('input');
 var newType = document.createAttribute('type');
 newType.value = 'text';
 var newName = document.createAttribute('name');
 newName.value = 'myText' + (lastInputX + 1);

 newInput.setAttributeNode(newType);
 newInput.setAttributeNode(newName);
 inputDiv.insertBefore(newInput,lastInput);
 inputDiv.insertBefore(lastInput,newInput);
    }

var button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
button.addEventListener('click',createNewInput,false);
```

```css
input {
display: block;
margin: 12px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
<button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
<div>
<input type="text" name="myText1" />
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This code will cause duplicate names for the added inputs if an input that isn't the last field is removed.  Example:  add myText1, add myText2, add myText3 - then remove myText2.  It will add another input named  myText3.

Comment: No it won't. It will add another input named `myText4`. Please read the code above and verify this for yourself.

Comment: Correct, but you will leave gaps.  And since you're not storing the newly created name/IDs anywhere, it will be difficult for him to retrieve the stored values without looping through the elements by class.

Comment: Please read the OP's original question again. The OP requires "that every input box is named differently". The OP never states that inputs may be deleted and certainly never mentions the necessity of storing values. Have you invented this whole idea that fields can be removed? There is nothing to indicate that this such functionality is required in the OP's envisioned setup.

Comment: I'm pretty shocked that you claim to have read the OP's question, yet you think I am "inventing" the "whole idea" of removing fields.  Maybe you should read it again, because he has a button that removes fields.  You know: the one with the "remove_field" class.  Anyways, you should probably be less sarcastic, especially since you have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: Ouch. Thanks for pointing that out, @stan. I genuinely did not notice that. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Few problems with your approach:

You have to make sure that the same name doesn't get added multiple times.  If someone adds myText1, myText2, and myText3 - and then they remove myText2, your logic will have x set at 3 - and adding another field will result in myText0, myText1, myText3, and another myText3.

So, we need to make sure that we don't add the same input multiple times.  By using the for-loop that you see below (instead of using the x variable), you'll avoid this problem and ensure that the lowest unused integer is used.

So if you add fields 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 - and then remove field 2, it will detect that field 2 doesn't exist and use that as the next name to add.  Obviously, they will be out of order (1, 3, 4, 5, 2) - but you avoid duplicates AND gaps, so you can easily access their values with other code.

Your .clone line is unnecessary - appending the div to the desired element will suffice.

There is no need to assign elements to variables if you're only going to reference them once.

By adding a class to your inputs, you can easily see how many of them already exist - and enable/disable the Add button accordingly.

Untested code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php
$num = 0;
echo '
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
    <div><input type="text" class="InputField" name="'.${'myText'.$num.}.'"></div>
</div>
';
?>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
        var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed

        $(".add_field_button").click(function(e){ 
            e.preventDefault();
            var newId = 1;
            for (var i=0;i<max_fields;i++){
            if ($("input[name='myText" + i + "']") == null){ //If this control doesn't yet exist, set newId
                newID = i;
                break;
            }
        }

    $(".input_fields_wrap").append('<div><input type="text" class="InputField" name="myText' + newId + '"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>');

    if ($(".InputField".length >= max_fields) //Disable add field button if the max number of fields has been met
        $(".add_field_button").prop("disabled", true);
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault(); 
    $(this).parent('div').remove(); //Remove the associated div
    $(".add_field_button").prop("disabled", false); //Enable the add field button
    })
});
</script>
```